# Зачем создавать внутриклассовую переменную?

Tags: ооп, php

Зачем создавать внутриклассовую переменную, если можно обойтись и без нее?
Этот кусок кода взял из книги, для простоты дал свои названия классам, свойствам, методам и т.д.)

Пример с внутриклассовой переменной

```
class Test
{
    public $test;

    public function test($test)
    {
        return $this -> test = $test;
    }

}
```

Пример без внутриклассовой переменной

```
class Test
{

    public function test($test)
    {
        return $test;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

в вашем случае вообще и функцию и класс создавать не надо...

а вот здесь например очень надо:

```
class Test
{
    public $test;

    public function get_test()
    {
        return $this -> test;
    }

    public function add($test)
    {        
        $this -> test+=$test;
    }

    public function __construct($test=0) {
        $this->test=$test;
    }

}
```

Comment: public function __construct($tes)
    {
        return $test;
    }

можно ж и так написать? зачем нужно вк переменные? я это не могу понять

Comment: чтобы в методе add их менять, вы называйте их "свойствами" и сразу поймете. (зачем  нужен цвет у трамвая ?)

Comment: блиииин( непоняяяятно)

Comment: что непонятно ? объект несет какие-то свойства, с помощью методов их можно менять, смотреть прочее. класс  описывает свойства и методы.

Comment: зачем нужно свойства? ведь можно прописывать параметры в методы и работать с ними. без конструкции $this->имя_свойства. сорри за глупые вопросы, просто огромное желание освоить это все...) думаю, вы меня понимаете.. сами ж были в этой шкуре

Comment: не не был. еще раз свойства нужны чтобы они принадлежали объекту. зачем вам имя (это ваше свойство) ? чтобы когда кто нибудь спросит "как вас зовут ?"(метод) вы ответили %username%,  а не было всегда так - "я вас буду звать %username%"

Comment: А почему `$test` -- `public`?

Comment: спасибо за терпение и время, уделенное мне) погуглю на эту тему((

Comment: @Mobyman - можно и private, но сути это не меняет.

Comment: @vinnie, что тут гуглить? Вам же только что все разжевали.
@eicto, инкапсуляция же.  Смысл тогда делать методы для установки и получения значения?

Comment: @vinnie, перечитайте свой учебник с того самого места, где начинается описание классов и внимательно читайте, вникая. Это самый лучший совет, поверьте мне. У вас пробел, который надо восполнить. Иначе продвижению вперед помешают многие другие факторы, которые встретятся вам далее.

Answer (score 0):

тебе надо понять концепцию классов вообще, а не просто, зачем нужно то и сё. В процедурном программировании ты рассматриваешь понятие "действие", то есть что нужно сделать, чтоб получить результат, а в ООП ты оперируешь "штучками", такими как машины, кошки, окна, узлы сети, пользователи и т.д., имеющими определенные свойства, такие как количество бензина, цвет, кличка, ширина и высота, массив дочерних объектов и т.д., вот эти своийства этих штучек (или, их называют объектами) и есть эти "внутриклассовые переменные". И кстати, их по большей части надо делать защищенными и закрытыми, а доступ из-вне давать через открытые функции. Например, можно изменить из-вне кличку кошку, но нельзя (или нежелательно) изменять количество лап, хвостов и голов

Comment: имя кошки тоже приватным должно быть :)

Comment: Что бы кошку нельзя было подменить другой кошкой

Comment: чтобы кто-попало не именовал.

Comment: @eicto, я об этом же ж.))